# Writing a file in byte mode and placing a line separator in Python

Tags: python-3.x, separator, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

I am trying to convert a MPEG-2 TS file into byte mode file and place some kind of a separator between the 188 bytes packets in Python3. This is my code:

```
def hex_conversion(inp_tsfile):
  with open(inp_tsfile, 'rb') as f:
    with open(out_hexfile, 'wb') as f_out:
      for packet in iter(lambda: f.read(188), b''):
        line = packet + codecs.encode("\n", 'utf-8')
        f_out.write(codecs.encode(line, 'hex'))
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't put the new line separator so the file appears uninterrupted, so I cannot reliably grep for strings inside it. If I switch from `f_out_write` to `print()` and execute the script forwarding the `stdout` to a file manually I got the right format.

[EDIT]: I want to have in the file something like this:

```
b'4700ff16d88afc34c6790be7abe766bc7669e9ad7c544f5f713c6d20e7866a76972eb96100f70618c5c8000d9f35f013760abda7f4e57db8f31ac1e14e16e31b33c6d44cbb7ecc20f97cebc4e8c6001573271c4460ec5c5336570b81f2d642251c6f4379f7c7ca694446751d19c3f5663ff809342f80f6244fae30d19fc16e7df860ca0b397c34385a35c33814e5770ef7218dda48c43e991fd55f8cd4406fa1cb8a3e536292f5fa0ef841972c9513784648924f039961ba1c9a7b600a'
b'471fff10f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7f808182838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9fa0a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9aaabac0a'
b'4700ff1731febdc7a2a34d6ce7b87922094b65e689887c151fe62cfcd6b74d1ea4e00a5f9a192b0e3d17e2b880027daa1336b953088bdf9303ef70783fcd49372dd48017404423646d65e00a31ef2b5cc033704a1ef31ff2c8e76cd9d3e19ae49abef8ea3d38d3db5093774ed3de3838b9e9d5eb63d4d67f4c4d081fa75e3062811f4bcb748b66f8f165292ffb9f48f90337ca26b3bd232a635fd7c0275abaf4a812f17bbaba3d51218628acfc540f68453f6f330cf5cd15d6647a840a'
```

So as you see I have on each line a new packet. This is actually the output if I execute the `print(codecs.encode(line, 'hex'))` command. Instead, my file is not separating the packets.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the solution, and I couldn't explain exactly why, but you should try opening `out_hexfile` with `'w'` instead of `'wb'`.

Comment: Well if you want the textual hex representation of the value, yes you should open the file as text. Please post a sample of the output you desire

Comment: @Pynchia, I have added some additional information under `[EDIT]` in my threat

Comment: @mkrieger1 if I open the out_hexfile as `w` Python expects me to write strings and not bytes.

Comment: Then go ahead and write strings.

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out with how to do it with the help of @mkrieger1:

```
def hex_conversion(inp_tsfile):
  with open(inp_tsfile, 'rb') as f:
    with open(out_hexfile, 'w') as f_out:
      for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(188), b''):
        pkt_hex = codecs.encode(chunk, 'hex')
        line = str(pkt_hex) + "\n"
        f_out.write(line)
```